# Magento 1 website translation

Tags: magento-1

Has anyone tried to translate their magento one website? 
We are looking at applejetty. Any suggestions?
Has anyone ever used applejetty or similar ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps below:

1. Go to admin >> system >> configuration >> developer
2. Open the Translate Inline tab and enable "Enabled for Frontend"
3. Now go to frontend after deleting the cache and here you can add translations.

For a second way, you have to go to app >> locale and select the country code folder and you can see a CSV file. From here you can also add your translation.

Hope this will help you.